# Error building tensorflow from sources - is there a requirement that gcc > v4.8?

Tags: installation, tensorflow

Receiving the following error when building from sources. My best guess is maybe my gcc version is 4.8 (I got TF to install on another box with gcc 5.4 on it)?

Other notables: CUDNN library V6 is installed at a location on LD_LIBRARY_PATH (I got that to work on another machine without issue). CUDA 8.0 libraries. Tensorflow version 1.1.0-rc1

```
ERROR: /home/dparks/opt/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD:39:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor:cuda_platform' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/dparks/.cache/bazel/_bazel_dparks/3d9d26948e3f70203789e48515e761a6/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
  external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -fPIE -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-march=native' '-std=c++11' '-march=native' -MD -MF bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/stream_executor/_objs/cuda_platform/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/stream_executor/_objs/cuda_platform/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.pic.o' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY -DTENSORFLOW_USE_JEMALLOC -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles -iquote external/jemalloc -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -iquote external/protobuf -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_sycl -iquote external/gif_archive -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/gif_archive -iquote external/jpeg -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/jpeg -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/highwayhash -iquote external/png_archive -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive -iquote external/zlib_archive -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/zlib_archive -iquote external/local_config_cuda -iquote bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_cuda -isystem external/jemalloc/include -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/jemalloc/include -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -isystem external/protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/src -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/gif_archive/lib -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/gif_archive/lib -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/png_archive -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/png_archive -isystem external/zlib_archive -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/zlib_archive -isystem external/local_config_cuda/cuda -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_cuda/cuda -isystem external/local_config_cuda/cuda/include -isystem bazel-out/local_linux-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/include -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -fno-canonical-system-headers -c tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc -o bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/stream_executor/_objs/cuda_platform/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In member function 'virtual bool perftools::gputools::cuda::CUDABlas::GetBlasGemmAlgorithms(std::vector<long long int>*)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1916:9: error: 'CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO5' was not declared in this scope
         CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO5, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO6, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO7}) {
         ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1916:28: error: 'CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO6' was not declared in this scope
         CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO5, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO6, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO7}) {
                            ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1916:47: error: 'CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO7' was not declared in this scope
         CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO5, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO6, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO7}) {
                                               ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1916:64: error: unable to deduce 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>&&' from '{CUBLAS_GEMM_DFALT, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO0, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO1, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO2, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO3, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO4, <expression error>, <expression error>, <expression error>}'
         CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO5, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO6, CUBLAS_GEMM_ALGO7}) {
                                                                ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasOperation_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasTranspose(perftools::gputools::blas::Transpose)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:410:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasFillMode_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasUpperLower(perftools::gputools::blas::UpperLower)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:421:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasDiagType_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasDiagonal(perftools::gputools::blas::Diagonal)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:432:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cudaDataType_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDAComputationType(perftools::gputools::blas::ComputationType)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:519:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc: In function 'cublasSideMode_t perftools::gputools::cuda::{anonymous}::CUDABlasSide(perftools::gputools::blas::Side)':
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:443:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.900s, Critical Path: 3.27s
```

Comment: This is better answered if you file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)